# Understanding Gunicorn Worker and Thread Configuration for Flask-SocketIO with Eventlet

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, gunicorn, eventlet

I'm developing a Flask web application that uses SocketIO and am facing issues with configuring Gunicorn, particularly with the number of workers and threads. My server runs on Ubuntu with 32GB DDR4 memory and an i7 7700k CPU. I've tried several configurations, but I'm puzzled by the performance results and SocketIO errors I'm encountering. Here's what happens with different commands:

1. **Basic Gunicorn Command:**

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
Result: Extremely poor performance and SocketIO errors.
```

2. **Increased Workers and Threads:**

```
gunicorn -w 12 -t 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
Result: Great performance but still SocketIO errors.
```

3. **Using Eventlet with One Worker:**

```
gunicorn -k eventlet -w 1 -t 100 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
Result: Great performance and no SocketIO errors.
```

4. **Using Eventlet with Two Workers:**

```
gunicorn -k eventlet -w 2 -t 100 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
Result: Great performance but back to SocketIO errors.
```

Given the above scenarios, I have several questions:

1. **Performance with Single Worker in Eventlet:**
   Why am I getting good performance in scenario 3 with only a single Eventlet worker? How does this single worker manage to handle the load effectively?
2. **SocketIO Errors with Multiple Workers:**
   Why do SocketIO errors reappear when I increase the number of workers (scenario 4) while using Eventlet? If `eventlet -w 1` is allocating single worker for eventlet, then is my program being allocated extra workers automatically? If not then why is my app performing good?
3. **Optimal Configuration for Performance and Stability:**
   Based on my server specs and the behavior observed, what would be the optimal Gunicorn configuration for balancing performance and stability with Flask-SocketIO and Eventlet?

Comment: what is your `Flask-SocketIO` version?

Comment: Flask-SocketIO==5.3.6 @TanThien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `eventlet` is good for `IO bound` tasks. So, you 'll get a good performance  with this type worker. Thread option `-t 100` mean the server will handle 100 request in the same time, when many requests come worker master load 100 request to child worker that deployed application. Because requests are mostly IO tasks, they are processed "concurrently" by eventlet mode. If you set a `few --thread`, the server is `low performance`
2. Through the [post](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html): due to the limited load balancing algorithm used by gunicorn, it is not possible to use more than one worker process when using this web server. For that reason, all the examples above include the `-w 1` option. So, if you use `Flask-SocketIO version < 2.0`, It doesn't support multiple workers and leads to errors. Each worker has a different memory area that leading client's request being divided among another worker that was not processed by the previous worker
3. Again in the post at [Using Multiple Workers](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#using-multiple-workers), You must use `Flask-SocketIO >= 2.0` and need a `queue` such as redis for many workers can get client connections of the other worker before increase number worker.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the reply. So, it is perfectly fine to `use eventlet -w 1`? I was worried, I'm missing out on potential performance buff since I can't use more workers.

Comment: @Daqs To say if it's fine or not with one worker. You must monitor resource your server using. Example, you use ubuntu with 32GB DDR4 memory and an i7 7700k CPU and you provide full resource but the server use only 20 % cpu, 20% ram => It is `bad`. If your server deploy in a container and you only provide provide 1 vcpu and 1gb ram, stress test use 80~90% cpu => ok  it's good. Final, To evaluate good or bad, you have to look at how you provide resources and stress test to know how much server use them

Comment: In addition, it also depends on usage needs. For example, the system only needs to respond to 50 requests at the same time, so you don't need to worry with one worker. Stress test to adjust configuration accordingly